# Trying to replace second or second last element of lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to write two predicates. They are to replace the second or second last element of a list with a given input element. So far I have only been able to replace the first element of a list or insert at position two. I am very new to Prolog and I am having some difficulties understanding the backtracking and recursion. Could anyone help me with this? The more detail in answer the better as I  really want to understand.

I call like this: `repl([1,2,3,4,5], new, Y).` and I am trying to get the result `Y = [1,new,3,4,5]` back. I am also trying to do the same to replace the second last one, like this: `repl2([1,2,3,4,5], new, Y).` which i want to return `Y = [1,2,3,new,5]`.

So far what i have tried is

```
repl([_], X, [X]).
repl([H|T], X, [H,X|T])
```

I know this is very wrong for many reasons. I have tried many different things but as I mentioned this syntax and this backtracking and recursion is a bit mind boggling to say the least.

Comment: What do you expect when the list is empty or has one element ? e.g `repl([],new,Y)` should succeed or fail??

Comment: I was able to figure out the first one. `repl([H,X|T], A, [H,A|T]).` This works for me. And returns false if list is 0 or 1 elements. Is that correct? Or should i have a case for empty list as well always? I want it to return false always if list is empty or has one element

Comment: Since you want to return false in case of 0,1 length of lists then it's fine. I'll give an answer for second one if you find it difficult...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already figure it out, for the `repl/3` predicate the definition is:

```
repl([H,_|T], A, [H,A|T]).
```

In the above definition watch the underscore (in your definition you had a variable X, use underscore to mute the singleton warning).

For the `repl2/3` definition you could write:

```
repl2(L, A, OutL):-reverse(L, [H,_|T]), reverse([H,A|T], OutL).
```

Example:

```
?- repl2([1,2,3,4,5], new, Y).
Y = [1, 2, 3, new, 5].
```